# Check existance with first method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to check if a record already exist in my database. In my function i have this code:

```
mailcode = params[:q]
check = User.where("custom_mailcode = 'mailcode'").first
```

Now i'm in trouble with the if statement. I think to do something like that:

```
if check == nil
  doing something
else
  doing something
end
```

But it doesn't work because check is never nil. How can i fix that?

Comment: This is weird, if no user is found matching the the given where-clause, calling `.first` would return `nil` so it should just work.

Comment: Sounds like a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What do you indend to do with that item in case it exists or not?

Comment: And FYI `where(...).first` is typically done via `find_by(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

User.where("custom_mailcode = 'mailcode'").any?

Comment: As a side-point, you might want to define the condition as a named scope. something like `named_scope :with_mailcode, lambda {|code| where(:custom_mailcode => code)}`

Comment: Well, any? returns true or false, so you wouldn't then do `if check == nil`, just `if check`.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to use the user record you can instead use `find_by`

```
user = User.find_by(custom_mailcode: params[:q]) # User / nil
if user
  # ...
else 
  # ...
end
```

`find_by` unlike where returns the first record or nil.

If you do not plan on using the database values than use `.any?` it will issue a `COUNT` SQL query which is slightly faster and uses less memory.

```
# ActiveRecord only loads a boolean into memory
if User.where(custom_mailcode: params[:q]).any?
  # ...
else 
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
if check.present?
  ...
else
  ...
end
```

Comment: Calling `.first` on a relation will either return `nil` or the first object, so while this more readable, how does this fix the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
if check = User.where(custom_mailcode: params[:q]).first
  p check
else
  doing something else
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ha I see the error, the error is not in your check, but in your where-clause. You are always looking for a fixed string called `mailcode`, not the value of the variable. The easiest fix is just to write the where differently:

```
check = User.where(custom_mailcode: params[:q]).first
```

Or use proper string interpolation

```
check = User.where("custom_mailcode = '#{mailcode}'").first
```

which you should avoid, because this makes your application vulnerable to SQL injection attacks; just showing the proper way to do string interpolation.

And then you just test

```
if check == nil
```

But I personally prefer `check.nil?`.

Comment: Use `find_by(ustom_mailcode: params[:q])` instead of `.where(custom_mailcode: params[:q]).first` the latter is just bad style.

Comment: Nope the return value is the same - if you don't need the user use `any?` or `count` which issues a count query.

Comment: Yes, I was very good at not really reading your comment apparently. I do not agree on the style argument, I find the `where-first` combination very readable, and it allows to combine various where clauses, as you usually do, and it results in the same query as the `find_by`. So imho it is just a matter of _personal_ taste to use either one. But it is a good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to modify or read the user if it's found. That can be accomplished like this:

```
mailcode = params[:q]
user = User.find_by(custom_mailcode: mailcode)
if user
  # do something with the user
else
  # backup logic
end
```

Or, as is often needed, you may want to create the object, if it's not already found. There's a `find_or_create_by` shorthand for that purpose:

```
mailcode = params[:q]
user = User.find_or_create_by(custom_mailcode: mailcode)
user.update(meaning_of_life: 42)
```